# Keyboard malfunction

Tags: drivers, keyboard, windows-8.1

I own a Razer Deathstalker and for the past couple of months have been experiencing weird symptoms with the keyboard. The issues when it first started occurring did not happen frequently, so I mostly ignored, however recently I've noticed my keyboard giving issues more often. My pc's operating system is Windows 8.1. I get the following symptoms randomly:

1. When turning on my computer or waking it up from sleep, the keyboard will sometimes become unresponsive and the only way to make it work is by unplugging and plugging it back into the pc.
2. The keys on the keyboard will become electronically stuck when waking from sleep mode or a cold bootup. This does not happen to just one key, it will randomly happen to any key where it will get stuck and the only way to fix is unplugging and plugging back in.
3. The main keys on the keyboard will work fine, but any special keys that the keyboard has (such as changing the volume) will not function properly. When this occurs, I notice that in the control panel under view devices it displays my keyboard with an error about the driver on it. If I try to fix the driver, nothing happens, but the second that I unplug and replug the error goes away and all of a sudden there is no more "bad driver."

I've already played around with the power settings on my computer to see if it may be a power setting that is affecting my keyboard, but that has not worked. Also, I've checked in the device manager, and have even tried reverting the driver on the keyboard to an older version of the driver before the issue became prevalent. The only temporary fix right now that always works is unplugging the keyboard and plugging it back in, however I want to see if there's a way to truly fix the problem. I'm not sure if I just have hardware failure and my keyboard's about to give out on me. Would anyone have any suggestions or ideas on what I could try?

Comment: This really sounds like a general hardware failure dealing with the PCB.

Comment: Is there any method to fix that or not? If not it doesn't matter much since I already have another keyboard, but if there is a way I'd like to save that keyboard since it was a really nice keyboard.

Comment: Unless you are a electronic engineer I don't know of a method to fix a broken PCB, if the keyboard malfunctions on entirely different system, its safe to say the hardware should be replaced.

Comment: Having just bought a new keyboard with apparently random failing keys, I have found another possible cause: Lack of power. The hub it was connected to claimed to supply 500 mA per port when it was bus-powered.

Answer (score 1):

I see this problem quite frequently. Try changing the following power management settings in device manager:

[image: Dev Manager]
[image: Power Management Options]

Answer (score 0):

I would make sure that you have checked to see if there are any available updates in the Razer Synapse 2.0 software. It would also be wise to check that you have the latest version, [available here](http://drivers.razersupport.com/index.php?_m=downloads&_a=viewdownload&downloaditemid=861&_m=downloads&_a=viewdownload&downloaditemid=861).

If you're up-to-date in that regard, then next thing I would check is the warranty. Razer keyboards come with a 1 year limited warranty in most places, so if you are within that period, you should be eligible for a replacement, or at the very least under warranty repairs.

Also, if you have access to another computer, I would see if you can reproduce the issue. There's nothing like assuming your peripheral is dead, when it's actually your computer that's slowing fading away.